# c, pthread_create gives segmentation fault ?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, segmentation-fault

I'm keep getting a segmentation fault from where I create thread and declare some variables in the struct...
Does anyone know why?

```
dispatch_queue_t *dispatch_queue_create(queue_type_t queueType){

int cores = num_cores();
printf("message-queuecreate1");

dispatch_queue_t *dispatch_queue = (dispatch_queue_t *) malloc(sizeof(dispatch_queue_t));
dispatch_queue->HEAD = NULL;
dispatch_queue->END = NULL;

//create a thread array for dispatcher and worker threads
dispatch_queue_thread_t *threads[cores+1];
threads[cores+1]= (dispatch_queue_thread_t *)malloc(sizeof(dispatch_queue_thread_t));

//create semaphores
sem_t queue_task_semaphore;
sem_t queue_thread_semaphore;
sem_t queue_wait_semaphore;

sem_init(&queue_task_semaphore, 0, 1);
sem_init(&queue_thread_semaphore,0,1);
sem_init(&queue_wait_semaphore,0,1);

dispatch_queue->queue_task_semaphore = queue_task_semaphore;
dispatch_queue->queue_thread_semaphore = queue_thread_semaphore;
dispatch_queue->queue_wait_semaphore = queue_wait_semaphore;




//create dispatcher thread      
//segmentation fault #1////////////////
threads[0]->current_task=NULL;
threads[0]->queue=dispatch_queue;

pthread_create(threads[0]->thread, NULL, dispatcher_threadloop, threads[0]);
//////////////////////////////////////  

if (queueType == CONCURRENT){
    int i = 0;
    int thread_id=0;
    //create worker thread array if the type of the queue is concurrent

    while(i<cores){

        //create worker thread

        thread_id = i+1;

        //segmentation fault #2//////////
        threads[i+1]->queue=dispatch_queue;
        threads[thread_id]->thread=NULL;
        threads[thread_id]->current_task=NULL;

        pthread_create(threads[thread_id]->thread, NULL, worker_threadloop, (void *)(long)i);
        ////////////////////////////////

        printf("thread %d is created\n",i);
        i++;
    }

} else {//do smth}
    //segmentation fault# 3////////////////
    threads[1]->thread=worker_thread;
    threads[1]->queue=dispatch_queue;
    threads[1]->current_task=NULL;
    //////////////////////////////////////
}



return dispatch_queue;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is riddled with problems:

Accessing threads[core + 1] is invalid. Also, you're not allocating memory for the `threads[0]` ... `threads[core]`.

```
dispatch_queue_thread_t *threads[cores+1];
threads[cores+1]= ....;
```

So these will fail:

```
threads[0]->current_task=NULL; /* See above. */

threads[i+1]->queue=dispatch_queue; /* Again, no memory allocated. */
```

There could be other problems but I would start by slashing the `cores+1` stuff and replacing it with:

```
for (i = 0; i < cores; i++) {
    threads[i] = malloc(sizeof(*threads[i]));
}
```

Comment: wow thanx that eliminate most of faults haha but I still have segmentation fault when I create the thread..
for example `pthread_create(&threads[0]->thread, NULL, dispatcher_threadloop, threads[0]);`

Comment: @Leanne Edit your question and add the definition of `dispatch_queue_thread_t`

Comment: it is fixed now, but can u just chek if my definition is ryt?

`struct dispatch_queue_thread_t{

  struct dispatch_queue_t *queue;
  pthread_t thread;
  sem_t thread_semaphore;
  struct task *current_task;
  int thread_id;
 };`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

```
threads[]->thread
```

is a pthread_t (and not a pthread_t *)

You need to give the reference:

```
pthread_create(&threads[thread_id]->thread, NULL, worker_threadloop, (void *)(long)i);
```

.

Comment: yeayea I tried that, and it gives me an error saying `dispatchQueue.c:72: warning: passing argument 1 of 'pthread_create' from incompatible pointer type` ..